# Logging with scriptella

Tags: logging, etl

Does anyone know how to instruct scriptella to log to catalina Log
What should one write in etl.xml to enable logging?

Answer (score 1):

Scriptella is using a standard JU logging mechanism. If you want to see all log messages of Scriptella in catalina.out, the easiest solution would be to append the following line to the conf/logging.properties file of the Tomcat installation:

```
scriptella.level=FINE
```

By default only Level.INFO messages are printed. See [Using java.util.logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_%28default%29)